# Is there a name for the 1st isodynamic point of the contact triangle?

Tags: triangles, triangle-centres

For a triangle △ABC, take the contact triangle (the pedal triangle of the incenter) △A′B′C′.
Does the first isodynamic point of △A′B′C′ have a name relative to △ABC?
(Is it one of the Kimberling centers?)

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3315496/coordinates-of-centres-of-central-triangles-with-respect-to-the-reference-triang) for how to work out barycentrics, and thus trilinears, of triangle-centres-of-central-triangles.