Given an arbitrary triangle as 3 Feuerbach points, can we always reconstruct the original triangle?

There are 4 tangency points $F,F_A,F_B,F_C$ of the nine-point circle with the incircle or excircles. Given an arbitrary triangle as 3 of these points, we can always reconstruct the original triangle (non-uniquely).

(It is difficult to distinguish the incircle with the excircles so we won't distinguish $F$ with $F_A,F_B,F_C$. The only requirement is that the triangle has the given points as three points among $F,F_A,F_B,F_C$.)

Analogous to "The incenter $I$ and excenters $J_A,J_B,J_C$ form an orthogonal system", I try to deduce relations of the 4 points $F,F_A,F_B,F_C$:
Let the Nine-point circle be the unit circle,
let  the incircle touches the sides at $X$, $Y$, and $Z$.
From this post, the center of the nine-point circle is $N=\frac{(X Y+Y Z+ZX)^2}{(X+Y)(Y+Z)(Z+X) }$, and the Feuerbach point is $F=\frac{X Y + Y Z + Z X}{X + Y + Z}$, the tangency point of the Nine-Point Circle and the $A$-excircle is $F_1=\frac{-X^2 Y^2+X^2 Y Z+X^3 Y-X^2 Z^2+X^3 Z-2 X Y^2 Z-2 X Y Z^2-Y^2 Z^2}{(X+Y) (X+Z) (X-Y-Z)}$, and the radius of the Nine-Point Circle is $-\frac{X Y Z}{(X + Y) (Y + Z) (Z + X)}$.
$z_0=F-N=-\frac{X Y Z (X Y+X Z+Y Z)}{(X+Y) (X+Z) (Y+Z) (X+Y+Z)}$
$z_1=F_1-N=\frac{X Y Z (X Y+X Z-Y Z)}{(X+Y) (X+Z) (Y+Z) (X-Y-Z)}$ and by cyclic permutation
$z_2=\dots,z_3=\dots$
We eliminate $X$, $Y$, $Z$ from $z_0,z_1,z_2,z_3$ and get
$$2 p^2 q s-4 p^2 r^2+p q^2 r+4 p r s+2 q r^2=0\tag1\label1$$
where $p, q, r, s$ are elementary symmetric polynomials in $z_0,z_1,z_2,z_3$.
So \eqref{1} is a symmetric homogeneous polynomial of degree $4$ in $z_0,z_1,z_2,z_3$.
Write it as a polynomial $p(z_0)$.
Let $F(s)=p(\frac{s}{z_1z_2z_3})$ be a polynomial with coefficients in $z_1,z_2,z_3$.
Surprisingly we can verify that, $F(s)=s^4\overline{F(1/\overline{s})}$, so $F(s)$ is a Conjugate reciprocal polynomial.
So $F(s)=0$ iff $F(1/\overline{s})=0$.
Let $f(x)=(1+ix)^4F(\frac{1-ix}{1+ix})$,
then $f(x)$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$.
There is a bijection between roots of $f(x)$ and roots of $p(z_0)$.
$$\frac{1-ix}{1+ix}\frac1{z_1z_2z_3}=z_0$$
There is a bijection between real roots of $f(x)$ and roots of $p(z_0)$ on $|z_0|=1$.

Returning to the original question, since the Feuerbach point $z_0$ is on the Nine-point circle, so $|z_0|=1$.
Given unit complex numbers $z_1,z_2,z_3$, then $z_0$ is a root of \eqref{1} on $|z_0|=1$, corresponding to a real root of $f(x)$.
I try to find example of unit complex numbers $z_1,z_2,z_3$ such that there is no root $z_0$ of \eqref{1} with $|z_0|=1$, so that there does not exist triangle with $z_1,z_2,z_3$ as the Feuerbach Triangle.
Mathematica code to generate a random sample of unit complex numbers $z_1,z_2,z_3$:
Block[{z1=Exp[I RandomReal[2Pi]],z2=Exp[I RandomReal[2Pi]],z3=Exp[I RandomReal[2Pi]]},Chop[Abs[z0]]/.NSolve[{0==2 p^2 q s-4 p^2 r^2+p q^2 r+4 p r s+2 q r^2/. {p->SymmetricPolynomial[1,{z0,z1,z2,z3}],q->SymmetricPolynomial[2,{z0,z1,z2,z3}],r->SymmetricPolynomial[3,{z0,z1,z2,z3}],s->SymmetricPolynomial[4,{z0,z1,z2,z3}]}}]]

Running the test a few times, there is always a root $z_0$ of \eqref{1} with $|z_0|=1$. So I didn't find a counterexample to the original problem.
Equivalently, to find unit complex numbers $z_1,z_2,z_3$ such that $f(x)$ has no real roots. Here I used this condition for the existence of real root of the degree 4 polynomial $f(x)$ but it is taking too long to compute.
Mathematica code to generate a random sample to test this:
Block[{z1=Exp[I RandomReal[2Pi]],z2=Exp[I RandomReal[2Pi]],z3=Exp[I RandomReal[2Pi]]},CountRoots[Chop[Simplify[(2 p^2 q s-4 p^2 r^2+p q^2 r+4 p r s+2 q r^2/. {p->SymmetricPolynomial[1,{z0,z1,z2,z3}],q->SymmetricPolynomial[2,{z0,z1,z2,z3}],r->SymmetricPolynomial[3,{z0,z1,z2,z3}],s->SymmetricPolynomial[4,{z0,z1,z2,z3}]}/.z0->((1-I x)/(1+I x))/(z1 z2 z3))(1+I x)^4]],x]]

Running the test a few times, $f(x)$ always have a real root. Continue to construct the original triangle, I see that sometimes $z_1,z_2,z_3$ are all on the excircles of the original triangle, sometimes one of them is on the incircle of the original triangle.

Footnote:
Here is an alternative proof of \eqref{1}, using the property $LFe+MFe=NFe$ proven here.
Let the incircle be the unit circle, $l,m,n,z$ be unit complex numbers corresponding to points $L,M,N,Fe$.
Substitute $LFe=|l-z|,MFe=|m-z|,NFe=|n-z|$ into the equation $(LFe+MFe+NFe)(LFe+MFe-NFe)(LFe-MFe-NFe)(LFe-MFe+NFe)=0$
(Mathematica code:
FullSimplify/@CoefficientList[Expand[(l^2 m^2 n^2)/(l^2 (m-n)^2+m^2 n^2-2 l m n (m+n)) z^2 (LFe+MFe+NFe)(LFe+MFe-NFe)(LFe-MFe-NFe)(LFe-MFe+NFe)/.{LFe->Sqrt[(l-z)(1/l-1/z)],MFe->Sqrt[(m-z)(1/m-1/z)],NFe->Sqrt[(n-z)(1/n-1/z)]}],z]

) we get
\begin{align*}\frac{l^2 m^2 n^2 \left(l^2-2 l (m+n)+(m-n)^2\right)}{l^2 (m-n)^2-2 l m n (m+n)+m^2 n^2}\\+\frac{4 l^2 m^2 n^2 (l+m+n)}{l^2 (m-n)^2-2 l m n (m+n)+m^2 n^2}x\\-\frac{2 l m n (l+m+n) (l (m+n)+m n)}{l^2 (m-n)^2-2 l m n (m+n)+m^2 n^2}x^2\\+\frac{4 l m n (l (m+n)+m n)}{l^2 (m-n)^2-2 l m n (m+n)+m^2 n^2}x^3\\+x^4=0\end{align*}
Let $p, q, r, s$ be elementary symmetric polynomials in the 4 roots $z_0,z_1,z_2,z_3$. Then
\begin{align*}s=\frac{l^2 m^2 n^2 \left(l^2-2 l (m+n)+(m-n)^2\right)}{l^2 (m-n)^2-2 l m n (m+n)+m^2 n^2}\\r=-\frac{4 l^2 m^2 n^2 (l+m+n)}{l^2 (m-n)^2-2 l m n (m+n)+m^2 n^2}\\q=-\frac{2 l m n (l+m+n) (l (m+n)+m n)}{l^2 (m-n)^2-2 l m n (m+n)+m^2 n^2}\\p=-\frac{4 l m n (l (m+n)+m n)}{l^2 (m-n)^2-2 l m n (m+n)+m^2 n^2}\end{align*}
Substitute $p,q,r,s$ into LHS of \eqref{1} and simplify, we get $0$.
(Mathematica code:
2 p^2 q s-4 p^2 r^2+p q^2 r+4 p r s+2 q r^2/.{p->-((4 l m n (m n+l (m+n)))/(l^2 (m-n)^2+m^2 n^2-2 l m n (m+n))),q->-((2 l m n (l+m+n) (m n+l (m+n)))/(l^2 (m-n)^2+m^2 n^2-2 l m n (m+n))),r->-((4 l^2 m^2 n^2 (l+m+n))/(l^2 (m-n)^2+m^2 n^2-2 l m n (m+n))),s->(l^2 m^2 n^2 (l^2+(m-n)^2-2 l (m+n)))/(l^2 (m-n)^2+m^2 n^2-2 l m n (m+n))}//Simplify

) So we proved \eqref{1}.

I would not work with the three  ex-Feuerbach centers but the vertices of the incentral triangle - Because X11 is the center of the spiral similarity that maps D, E, F (the vertices of the incentral triangle) to X(11)a, X(11)b, X(11)c

I am more interested in the original question. Do you know which triangle center X(1) is (wrt the incentral triangle)?

@DuongNgo No, I failed to find which triangle center X(1) is (wrt the incentral triangle). but here is a similar result: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3324612/

Please state one clear question. From the text as it is it is hard (for me) to isolate the question. Problems appear first as questions, at some point there is an equation denoted by $(1)$, its L.H.S. is a polynomial, please make clear if the problem is related to the equation and translate NSolve. The question "What is the condition for 4 points to be the Feuerbach points of some triangle?" is unclear. What is that "some triangle" ? The triangles in the plane build a $6$-dimensional variety, and $(1)$ is one (complex?) condition. Adding one more, $|z_0|=1$ adds one more real condition.

@dan_fulea sorry for the lack of clarity, I mean "condition for there to exist a triangle, whose Feuerbach points are the given points".

Please keep edits to a minimum!

@Shaun Ok, now I need to make an edit, to fix a mistake.

Wait a while first. Maybe you could make a better edit, with multiple corrections . . .

@hbghlyj Update: My above comment is incorrect. $DX(11)a, EX(11)b, FX(11)c$ pass through $X(11)$ and $DEF, X(11)a.X(11)b.X(11)c$ are directly similar, but the similitude center is not $X(11)$. It is the anti-Steiner point of $X(3)X(500)$ w.r.t the incentral triangle.
